# scilab: adding vector to matrix

Tags: matrix, scilab

if I want to add an element to a vector in scliab I can use `$+1` index:

```
-->t($+1)=rand()
 t  =

    0.2113249  

-->t($+1)=rand()
 t  =

    0.2113249  
    0.7560439  

-->t($+1)=rand()
 t  =

    0.2113249  
    0.7560439  
    0.0002211  

-->t($+1)=rand()
 t  =

   0.2113249  
   0.7560439  
   0.0002211  
   0.3303271
```

So why if I want to add a row or column to an empty matrix I get a zero row or column?

```
-->U(:,$+1)=t
 U  =

    0.    0.2113249  
    0.    0.7560439  
    0.    0.0002211  
    0.    0.3303271  

-->U(:,$+1)=t
 U  =

    0.    0.2113249    0.2113249  
    0.    0.7560439    0.7560439  
    0.    0.0002211    0.0002211  
    0.    0.3303271    0.3303271  

-->Z($+1,:)=t'
 Z  =

    0.           0.           0.           0.         
    0.2113249    0.7560439    0.0002211    0.3303271  

-->Z($+1,:)=t'
 Z  =

    0.           0.           0.           0.         
    0.2113249    0.7560439    0.0002211    0.3303271  
    0.2113249    0.7560439    0.0002211    0.3303271
```

Best regards
Max

Comment: I get the same results, no matter if the `U` and `t` are empty or completely undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly a bug can you report it on http://bugzilla.scilab.org/